# How do you set a scheduled task that can run a program in the foreground as an administrator, triggered by any user?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler, privileges, tasks

For context incase I am looking at this wrong: I'm working on building my little sisters a computer with RGB and the GUI will only launch from an Admin account. I do not fully trust them with Administrator access yet, but I want them to be able to open this software. Windows 10 20H2

So far, I have tried creating a task that I can launch with `schtasks /run /tn "StartPolychromeSync"` and saved this in a shortcut in `Public Desktop`. The task action starts the program with "highest privileges." The issue is that this task can not be ran by local non-admin accounts.
The task action works to launch the program when my account is specified, so I then set the group to `BUILTIN/Users` instead. This then caused all Users to lose access to manually trigger the task. When I use an administrative cmd to trigger it, the process starts but as a Background Task which defeats the purpose.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Execute it via `RUNAS /savecred`.

Comment: I have just tried this and it seems that the task action has run but only if my account is disconnected (but still signed in). It seems to also still be a background task when executed this way.  My other concern with savecred is that it saves this in the Credentials and from there I am not sure if they could potentially execute other things elevated

Comment: If you need the interface to be visible then you must execute the task from current account. If you need to execute the program using some definite credentials then you must use RunAs. If you need highest privileges then create a link file, set "running with high privileges" in its properties, and execute this link instead of the executable. PS. Using `psexec -i` is also an option.